# Angular-cli error during the npm commands

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules

Error while running the cmd ng, ng generate component header. I suspect it is because it couldn't find module 'ansi-colors'.
I tried npm i -g ansi-colors but didn't work for me.
I'm fairly new to Angular. Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

```
➜  my-app git:(master) ✗ ng
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-colors'
Require stack:
- /Users/p*****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js
- /Users/p*****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /Users/p*****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/p*****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js:11:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/p*****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js',
    '/Users/p*****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js',
    '/Users/p*****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng'
  ]
}
```

**Package.json** for reference. It has the ansi-color under dependencies. Is it a problem with my machine or installing the packages ? I tried all possible installation of ansi-color globally in my machine.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.4",
    "ansi-colors": "^4.1.1",
    "ansicolors": "^0.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try `npm install` ?

Comment: Yes i did try `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` multiple times now.

Comment: also try uninstalling `ansi-colors` globally, and let it gets installed automatically with `npm start`.

Comment: Thanks @yaya, I did try `npm uninstall ansi-colors` , `npm uninstall -g ansi-colors`. I reinstalled the node-modules and did `npm start`. It still showing me the same error.

Comment: 1. try to create a new project: `ng g new newproj` and check if it does fix it. 2. actually you're using nvm and i'm not familar enogh with it. maybe you're intstalling it on another npm version. it seems that it expects to see this module on this path: `/Users/p*****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules`. i know it's crazy but try to copy a the `ansi-colors` manually to that path, if it's not there (after `npm i -g ansi-colors`). another possible issue: you upgraded your node version, but not angular cli or npm versions.

Comment: Yes, all this time I have been installing in another nvm version. I had two versions of node installed on my machine and I just noticed that. Once I changed the nvm version it works just fine. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: No problem. happy coding :)